# What is the difference between Algebraic Expressions and Polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, terminology

Both algebraic expressions and polynomials are a combination of terms grouped together. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Polynomial" is a precisely defined term.  A polynomial is constructed from constants and variables by adding and multiplying.  One could add "subtracting", but $x-y$ is $x+(-1)y$, so adding and multiplying are enough.

"Algebraic expression" is not a precisely defined term.  Algebraic expressions include many things that are not polynomials, including rational funtions, which come from dividing polynomials, and things like $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: So the difference is that the polynomials can only include +/-/÷/x, variables, coefficients and constants, while algebraic expressions can include anything, for e.g. square roots?

Comment: Yes. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Artemisveras : Actually one should not allow division.  The set of polynomials is closed under addition, subtraction, and multiplication, but not division. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So if there's division in an expression, it's not a polynomial?

Comment: @Artemisveras : One can divide by scalars, since one just gets another scalar, and those are allowed.  But dividing by anything containing variables will get you something that is not a polynomial, unless that factor in the denominator cancels out because the same factor appears in the numerator. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Some difference is:

Algebraic Expression: may not be a continuous function on $R = (-\infty,\infty)$, but Polynomial is.
**Example:** $\dfrac{x}{x+1}$, and $x^2-1$. The former is not defined at $x=-1$, while the latter is continous throughout $R$.